# Slide event of Pivot Built with WinJs doesn't work on windows Phone

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, touch, winjs, slide

Hi i built a pivot with winJs but trying this on my Windows Phone the only way to navigate between PivotItems, is the menu. How can i fix this? Thanks

```
<div id="pivotScenario3" class="wide" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{ selectedIndex: 1 }">
     <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Circolari', managedLV: true }">
     <div id="content1"></div>
</div>


<div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'News', managedLV: true }">
    <div id="content"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way:

```
<div id="pivotScenario3" class="wide" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{ selectedIndex: 1 }">
    <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'Circolari', managedLV: true }">
        <div id="content1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'News', managedLV: true }">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```